# Approximating a function

Tags: functions, approximation, approximation-theory

I'm sorry if this question in not well formed...

I would like to perform a computation of the following function:

```
f() = -2*X1 -1*X2 +0*X3 + 1*X4 +2*X5
```

(The function can be of more variables, but is always finite and the coefficients are always of this form: -n..-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,..n ). Each Xi is also a sum other xi's, that is:

Xi = (xi1 +xi2 + ... xim).

I need some kind of approximation or something like that so I will be able to compute this efficiently, with limit set of operations, because n and m can be large numbers and I need to run this in MATLAB many times.

I can compute sums of the xi's and the Xi's very efficiently, (in O(1)), and I would like if possible to use this.

Suggestions for additional information and examples will be welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems to be ineteresting and I work with such sums lot; but your description is realy foggy to th reader. Can you take some time and describe the problem you have very diligently and in a dedicated way in details so that I get what you really have and what and for which purpose of *efficiency* you want to use it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I edited my question, I hope it is better now... let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be resumed to the following form:

$$f(x_{i,j})=\sum^n_{i=1} a_{i} X_{i}=\sum^n_{i=1} a_{i} \sum^m_{j=1} x_{i,j}$$

with $a_i \in \Bbb Z$. For the largest coefficient $a_{i}^{max}$ you could define:

$$g(x_{i,j})=a_{i}^{max} \sum^n_{i=1} \sum^m_{j=1} x_{i,j}$$

$f$ would not exceed $g$. It should be to good extent efficient to calcualte $f\approx g$. I hope I understood your question correct.

---

possible optimization

$$g(x_{i,j})=g^{(p)}-|g^{(n)}|=p_{i}^{max} \sum^k_{i=1} \sum^l_{j=1} x_{i,j}-|n_{i}^{max}| \sum^k_{i=1} \sum^l_{j=1} y_{i,j}$$
while $p$ is for positive and $n$ for negative integers.
Then approximate separately:
$$f^{(p)}\approx g^{(p)}$$
$$f^{(n)}\approx |g^{(n)}|$$
So you may split your approximation to avoid *cancellation* in the series' approximation.

Comment: Hi, My problem is not the programming language, rather than the method I use, mathematically. I want some kind of approximation because I want the computation be independent of the size of the variables. The code is very straight forward of course. I'm looking  to avoid the multiplications or minimize them as possible, or something similar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... the series is finite, should that matter?

Comment: Got your point, see suggestion above.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your edit, I just find it hard to understand how g approximates f, the expression ∑i=1n∑j=1mxi,j equals to X1 + X2 +...Xn? could you please give a more detailed explanation ? thanks!

Comment: ok, say the case is: a = {-1,0,1}, X = {2,3,5}, where X1 = (1+1), X2= (1+2) , X3=(3+2):  then f is: -1*2 + 0*3 + 1*5 = 3. g is: 1*(2+3+5) ? or some kind of optimization is still required here?

Comment: yes. This would be indeed a result of a such a big $\mathcal O$ approximation as you asked for. Such approximation must wrap the whole possibilities of variations, and the bandwidth of your variations due number of parameter is such high. I have not tried it, but, what if you separate the negative and positive series and have this big $\mathcal O(N)$ applied to each of them and then subtract?

Comment: see above extension.